# Show error message when using batchmode

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compiling

Consider the following MWE (in a `foo.tex` file):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\begin{theorem*}
 Undefined star theorem environment
\end{theorem*}
\end{document}
```

If I now run `pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -file-line-error foo.tex` I get the following output in the console (as seen in the image below)

```
foo.tex:12: 
foo.tex:14:
```

This means that  only the file name and line number of the error are printed. Is there a way to also print the error message when using batchmode? This means that I would like to get something like:

```
foo.tex:12: LaTeX Error: Environment theorem* undefined.
foo.tex:14: LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{theorem*}.
```

instead of just

```
foo.tex:12: 
foo.tex:14:
```

[image]

**Edit:** The strange thing is that some error messages are in fact printed even when using `batchmode`. For instance if I write a new line containing `\error` after `\begin{document}` and then compile the document,  I get the following output:

[image]

Why is it that in this case the error message is printed?

Comment: Doesn't happen to me; probably it's specific of MiKTeX.

Comment: @egreg so `batchmode` should always print error messages?

Comment: No, I mean that I get *no* error message on the terminal in either case (which is the purpose of `batchmode`). I think that the command window has no batch mode capabilities, so something gets written anyway. On Unix systems, batchmode suppresses output (after the banner).

Comment: @egreg but you do get the file name and line number of the error? Or `batchmode` suppresses the error altogether?

Comment: After `entering extended mode` I get no other output.

Comment: @egreg ahh ok, thanks. Basically I use `batchmode` to suppress warnings that are fixed by successive runs (but I thought that `batchmode` still aborted on errors, showing the corresponding error message).

Comment: I get the correct (no output after `entering extended mode`) output here with MiKTeX: presumably something is not quite right with your set up.

Comment: @JosephWright and @egreg: I guess then there might be a problem with my setup. However I have no idea what that problem is. If one of you can, in the form an answer, explain how should `batchmode` theoretically/correctly work (and compare it for instance to `nonstopmode`, I will happily accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

If I use the command line

```
> pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -file-line-error test
```

and press Return, here's the output I get on the terminal

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

although the file starts with `\error` and, indeed, the log file shows

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.7.4)  4 JUL 2015 23:41
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \error

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I'm using a standard terminal on a Unix system (Mac OS X, but it's the same on other Unix boxes I tried) with TeX Live. Joseph Wright confirms that this is the behavior also on a Windows command shell with MiKTeX.

Note that `-interaction=nonstopmode` is *very* different: it makes TeX not stop at errors, showing them on the terminal window *along with the normal output*, so I get something like

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
./test.tex:1: Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \error

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
[...]
```

which is probably what you *don't* want.

TeX Live has the script `texfot` that filters messages on the terminal; if I run

```
> texfot pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error test
```

the terminal shows

```
/usr/texbin/texfot: invoking: pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
./test.tex:1: Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \error
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 19010 bytes).
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `nonstopmode` instead of `batchmode`? As far as I know `nonstopmode` does the same as the normal mode, but does not hold on errors. `batchmode` is intended not to put a lot of output to the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While this seems to be a good suggestion and might well be what the OP is looking fot, it is a bit meagre for an answer and in its current form is better suited as a comment. If you, however decide to add a short explanation, it might well become a very good answer (and wait for the OP's response).

Comment: You are right, I intended to post a comment. Sorry for that.

As far as I know `nonstopmode` does the same as the normal mode, but does not hold on errors. `batchmode` is intended not to do a lot of output to the terminal.

Comment: You can edit your answer to include that explanation.